# Angularjs dynamic html string compilation with an directive included inside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

I have been trying a dynamic html string parsing with recursive directives which works but two-way binding doesn't seems to be working.Need a little help here.Below is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ovz2RJDmnHPgLUqUaH7M
Here is the Code:

```
 var model = angular.module('modelApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

model.controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',
  function($scope, $window) {
    var modalctrl = this;
    modalctrl.form = {};

    $scope.showMeModalValues = function(){
      console.log(modalctrl.form);
    };
  }
]);

model.directive('contentInput', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      require: '^ngController',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        element.html('<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.form.' + attrs.name + '" />');
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    };
  }
]);

model.directive('dynamicInput', ['$compile', '$sce',
  function($compile, $sce) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
      require: '^ngController',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var html = '<content-input name=' + attrs.name + '></content-input>';
        scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
      }
    };
  }
]);

model.directive('reCompile', ['$compile',
  function($compile){
    return {
      require: '^ngController',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
        scope.$watch(attrs.reCompile , function(value){
          element.html(value);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: why are you trying to store HTML in JavaScript Variables? What does this accomplish that you couldn't do with defining your data and using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: What are you trying to gain? Two way binding. You mean ctrl.form? Instead of ng-model="ctrl.modalctrl.form.' use ng-model="modalctrl.form.' then console.log works perfectly

Comment: @Claies: I have been trying to form a html elements by parsing XML tags(which holds information regarding a element and element type) which is why i have been trying it out this way.

Comment: you mean like formly? http://docs.angular-formly.com/

Comment: or, like schema form? http://schemaform.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem!! Assiging scope.ctrl with ctrl resolves the issue of not updating  modalctrl.form
Plunker with working solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/ovz2RJDmnHPgLUqUaH7M

```
model.directive('dynamicInput', ['$compile', '$sce',
  function($compile, $sce) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
      require: '^ngController',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.ctrl = ctrl;
        var html = '<content-input name=' + attrs.name + '></content-input>';
        scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: As i understood html string in dynamicInput directive is compiled at reCompile directive with ng-model as ctrl.form.(attr.name) where we copile it with scope ng-model doesn't know what this ctrl as it is not binded with scope.So, assigning scope.ctrl with ctrl helped in ng-model values reflecting at modalctrl.form

Comment: @Claies: Thanks for your suggestions i have not explored libraries which helps in building forms with json data...thanks you for pointing those libraries.

Comment: @georgeawg: Thanks for your answer!! You can even look into my answer which resolves my issue.